# In prometheus I added ec2 instances details but it is showing down

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

In Prometheus, I added ec2 instances details but it is showing down.

[image]

Comment: I doubt there is enough information here to be able to help. You've added two images - are they identical? If so please edit the question to include just one. You might want to add more information too.

Comment: Wild guess (as halfer said, there's not enough information on your setup): Have you checked that it's not a network or firewall issue? Are you running Prometheus directly on the EC2 instance or as Docker container?